# How necessary is it to put sealer on a painted dresser?

Tags: paint, sealing, wooden-furniture

I sanded and painted a wooden dresser. The rep at Lowe's said I don't need a separate sealer, but that sounds fishy to me. Should I put sealer on it too?

Comment: what exactly did you paint the wooden dresser with?

Answer (score 1):

A sealer shouldn't be necessary unless you like the look better.

If you do decide to try a sealer, you need to select one that is compatible with the paint that you used.

It's always a good idea to try out your planned finishing steps on scrap.  You can try several variations and decide what looks best.